# extbase Repository: Access refference datarecord of defaultLang when in other lang

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have an extension (Lets call it Mystuff) with a refference to another extension (In the Model of Mystuff):

```
/**
* shoeref
*
* @var \My\MyCollection\Domain\Model\MyCollection
*/
protected $shoeref;
```

In the template I simply access it with `{mystuff.shoeref.image}`

Now the problem is, that MyCollection does not exists in all languages, while Mystuff exists in all langauges. As Example lets say we are in the language `L=1` where MyCollection does not exist. In this case `{mystuff.shoeref}` is NULL.

What I would like to do is to access the MyCollection data record of the Default language (regardless if there is a MyCollection record in this langauge, just always get the data record of the Default language would be fine). But I have no clue how to do that.

An Alternative that **works** is to create a data record for the `all` langauge (`L=-1`). But I dislike this solution as every editor then can edit this data record and it will always be just a copy of the default language data record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that extbase will use indeed fetch all child records with lang uid 1 and ignore the default records (with lang uid 0)

you can try to set `$querySettings->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);` but then you will get all records, regarding the translation settings.

this is still a pittfall in extbase.

I would write my own query statement to first fetch the parent records and then fetch the child records based on what is needed and not rely in extbase magic fetching mechanism.

some info:

https://wiki.typo3.org/Default_Orderings_and_Query_Settings_in_Repository

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

Comment: Thank you for the informations. Helped alot. On another place I have a kinda similar problem. In a Repository I try the function from your first link: `$query->getQuerySettings()->setSysLanguageUid(0);`  This leads to `Fatal error: Call to undefined method ...\Typo3QuerySettings::setSysLanguageUid()`. From your link I see the documentation is only for `extbase 6.0 - 6.2`. But I have extbase 7.6. Any chance there is a newer version of this documentation?

Comment: Ok I checked the QuerySettingsInterface.php directly and found out the function is now called `setLanguageUid()`. Could not found any documentation up to date..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is kind of simple:

**1st) Extend the model**
Add an additional getter in the model

```
public function getParentRecord() {
   return $this->_localizedUid;
}
```

This will return the uid of the parent record

**2nd) Create an additional viewhelper**

Create the file `typo3conf/ext/<your-ext>/Classes/ViewHelpers/ObjectViewHelper`:

```
<?php

namespace <YourVendor>\YourExtKey>\ViewHelpers;

class ObjectViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function render($id) {
        $rawRecord = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetSingleRow('*', '<tx_extkey_domain_model_fo>', 'uid=' . (int)$id);

        $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
        /* @var $dataMapper \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper */
        $dataMapper = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Mapper\\DataMapper');

        $records = $dataMapper->map('YourVendor\YourExtKey\Domain\Model\YourModel', array($rawRecord));
        $record = array_shift($records);

        $this->templateVariableContainer->add('obj', $record);
        $output = $this->renderChildren();
        $this->templateVariableContainer->remove('obj');
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to adopt all places of the vendor, the table name, and the model!

**3rd: Adopt the view**

Now change your template and use the new ViewHelper

```
<f:if condition="{model.parentRecord} > 0">
  <c:object id="{model.parentRecord}">
    <f:debug>{obj}</f:debug>
  </c:object>
</f:if>
```

You will now get the parent record